# Get data from Heroku Postgres externally using database url in python

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to access my Heroku Database from an external application. I have the link to the postgres url for my Heroku app, but I am unable to get the data from the database. I have tried the following:

```py
import psycopg2
import os

DB_URI=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')

conn=psycopg2.connect(DB_URI)
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM USER;")

print(cur.fetchone())
```

But I get a random name instead of the data I need. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to connect to the DB.

Your connection with the Postgres DB is OK, because `psycopg2` would raise `OperationalError` or the like otherwise.

The "random name" you're getting with `SELECT * FROM USER` is in fact your Postgres username (which Heroku defines for you), and that's exactly what you asked by performing this query.

You have to write a correct SQL query, which depends of you needs.

For exemple, if you have your data stored in a table called `myapp_mytable`, `cur.execute("""select * from myapp_mytable""")` will work like a charm.

Comment: So is the user table restricted / predefined?

Comment: Yes, `user` is a reserved keyword and can't be used as an usual table name.

Comment: +1 In my sqlalchemy, I had defined a table called ```"user"```. In order to get info from that table, I had to run ```SELECT * FROM "USER"``` because ```user``` without quotes is restricted.